# How to export .png in Inkscape running in Ubuntu?

Tags: inkscape

I desperately try to export my work in .png but when i want to chose the path Desk, it always goes to `run/user/1000/doc` and a file number where finally I can't even find my export.

How to properly export the PNG files?

Comment: You probably installed inkscape ssnap which has issues accessing the file system. Install with apt instead. Try the command `sudo snap remove inkscape &&  sudo apt install inkscape`

Comment: A big thank you!

Comment: I have rewritten the comment as an answer. You can accept that if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you installed inkscape snap which has issues accessing the file system. Remove the snap version, and install with apt instead. Enter the following commands one by one

```
sudo snap remove inkscape
sudo apt install inkscape
```